# Iterating through all the subfolders of a folder in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iteration, directory

IS there any efficient way to iterate through all the subfolders I've created inside my iphone App's Documents folder ? (Of course, without knowing their names or how many there are...)

Thanks...
Guy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for [`-[NSFileManager enumeratorAtPath:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-CHDDDIED). It contains sample code that does what you want.